# Store Array of Json Objects In Postgresql Using Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I am currently trying to store two lists of json objects into my postgresql database using psycopg2 without success.

Here's a snippet of what I am trying to do...

```
SQL_INSERT_QUERY = """INSERT INTO table (
                              x,
                              json_list_one,
                              json_list_two
                            ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""

def insert_stuff(id, json_list_one, json_list_two):
values = (
    id,
    map(psycopg2.extras.Json, json_list_one),
    map(psycopg2.extras.Json, json_list_two)
)
conn = get_connection_pool().getconn()
try:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(SQL_INSERT_QUERY, values)
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
finally:
    get_connection_pool().putconn(conn)
```

This current implementation is resulting in this error...

```
An exception of type ProgrammingError occured. Arguments:
('column "json_list_one" is of type json[] but expression is of type text[]\nLINE 5: ...) VALUES (\'9527d790-31dc-46fa-b683-c6fc9807c2a4\', ARRAY[\'{"h...\n                                                             ^\nHINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.\n',)
```

Does anyone know how I am supposed to insert an array of json objects in PostgreSQL?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45150668/3598837
this answer solved it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need cast value to son --

```
SQL_INSERT_QUERY = """INSERT INTO table (
                              x,
                              json_list_one,
                              json_list_two
                            ) VALUES (%s, %s::json[], %s::json[])"""
```

And if you use PostgreSQL 9.5 or later you need querying over json fields  is better to change json to jsonb. Jsonb allow to create GIN index than allow increase performance of your query.

Comment: This returns `DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information` . what could be wrong?

Comment: By default postgres cast unknown data as text. As you can see in error `'column "json_list_one" is of type json[] but expression is of type text[]` than error  in bad type for field - `text[]` instead `json[]`.

Answer (score 0):

from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45150668/3598837

```
from psycopg2.extras import Json

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('INSERT into some_table (uuid, dict) values (%s, %s)',
    ['testName', Json([{'name':'test','number':'444-444-4444'}, {'name':'test','number':'555-555-5555'}])])
#the rest of it
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to use the `json` library and call `json.dumps(dict_here)`. Json is not a supported type in Postgres. You use `json.dumps` to turn a dictionary into a json string, and `json.loads` to turn it back into a dictionary.

Comment: Actually PosgreSQL does support Json type (since 9.3?). I have stored Json (not as an array) in other tables.