# Preserve Python None/NULL when storing JSON in Postgres

Tags: python, json, postgresql, null

I have a PostgreSQL database table that has a JSON datatype column. When I store JSON strings in the database, `None` is not preserved. This can be reproduced with this code snippet:

```
import json,psycopg2

dictionary = {}
dictionary[None] = 0

conn = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='testdb' user='postgres' 
password='postgres'")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO testtable (json_column) VALUES (%s)""", 
(json.dumps(dictionary), ))
cursor.execute("""SELECT json_column FROM testtable""")
result = cursor.fetchall()[0][0].keys()[0]

print result
print type(result)
if result is None:
    print 'result is None'
else:
    print 'result is not None'
```

The output of this Python code is:

```
drew@debian:~/python$ python test.py
null
<type 'unicode'>
result is not None
drew@debian:~/python$
```

How can I store `None` as a key in the JSON column? The JSON object also has keys for `'None'` and `'null'`, so the value stored must be `None` or `null`.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You should use a [JSON *column type* in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150617/adding-dict-object-to-postgresql)...

Comment: You can't have `None` (or `null`, the JSON equivalent) be a key in a JSON object. Your dict simply isn't compatible with the JSON format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html#section-4):

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  **A name is a
> string.**

And from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps):

> Keys in key/value pairs of JSON are always of the type str. **When a
> dictionary is converted into JSON, all the keys of the dictionary are
> coerced to strings.**

JSON **does not have any concept of non-string dict keys**. If you want those, you don't want JSON. The closest you'll get with JSON is detecting the string `None` gets converted to and hoping that you never need to actually use the string `'null'` as a dict key.

Comment: Is there another dictionary-like datatype that can handle non-string keys?

Comment: @Drew: You may be interested in [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML).